# How can I convert a chained if statement checking multiple values to a case statement in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, switch-statement

I have an if elif elif else fi statement I want to convert to a case statement in bash scripting. Here is the code:

```
if [[ -n $1 ]] && [[ -n $2 ]] && [[ -n $3 ]]; then
    # sudoed audit or fsr w/ IP: set user, user home directory, IP.
    CURR_USER="$1";
    CURR_HOME="$2";
    ADDR="$3";
  elif [[ -n $1 ]] && [[ -n $2 ]] && [[ -z $3 ]]; then
    # sudoed audit or fsr w/o IP: set user, user home directory.
    CURR_USER="$1";
    CURR_HOME="$2";
    ADDR='';
  elif [[ -n $1 ]] && [[ -z $2 ]] && [[ -z $3 ]]; then
    # root w/ IP: set audit user, audit home directory, IP.
    CURR_USER='audit';
    CURR_HOME='/home/audit';
    ADDR="$1";
  else
    # root w/o IP: set audit user, audit home directory.
    CURR_USER='audit';
    CURR_HOME='/home/audit';
    ADDR="";
  fi
```

I tried the following and it didn't work

```
case $# in
   [[ -n $1 ]] && [[ -n $2 ]] && [[ -n $3 ]] )
    # sudoed audit or fsr w/ IP: set user, user home directory, IP.
    CURR_USER="$1";
    CURR_HOME="$2";
    ADDR="$3";;
  [[ -n $1 ]] && [[ -n $2 ]] && [[ -z $3 ]] )
    # sudoed audit or fsr w/o IP: set user, user home directory.
    CURR_USER="$1";
    CURR_HOME="$2";
    ADDR='';;
  [[ -n $1 ]] && [[ -z $2 ]] && [[ -z $3 ]] ) 
    # root w/ IP: set audit user, audit home directory, IP.
    CURR_USER='audit';
    CURR_HOME='/home/audit';
    ADDR="$1";;
  *                                         )
    # root w/o IP: set audit user, audit home directory.
    CURR_USER='audit';
    CURR_HOME='/home/audit';
    ADDR="";;
  esac
fi
```

The reason why I need a case statement is my boss thinks a case statement will be easier to understand down the road than an if elif else statement

Comment: Why do you want a `case` statement? This doesn't look like a particularly good fit for one.

Comment: `case $# in 3) ..;; 2) ..;; 1) ..;; 0) ..;; esac`

Comment: @thatotherguy, `yourprogram '' '' ''` will still have `$#` be 3, even though `-n` will be false for all of them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow's guidelines require _practical_, answerable questions. `if` is more practical than `case` in the scenario at hand.

Comment: BTW, note that all-caps names are used for variables that modify behavior of the shell and POSIX-specified utilities -- your own variables should have at least one lower-case character in their names. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a single namespace.

Comment: my boss wants a case statement

Comment: Your boss is asking for something harder to maintain than your original code. If you look at the example `case` statement in my answer, it's _very_ ordering-dependent; someone modifying it needs to keep a bunch of caveats in mind when making changes.

Comment: Anyhow, point them here; I'd be happy to extend my answer as necessary to make the case.

Comment: (_Also_, because a `case` statement can only match on a single value -- even if it's a composite value -- that means you absolutely _must_ have a sigil separating the fields, so any value being passed as an argument containing that sigil will break all the logic).

Comment: @AntonioContreras Are you sure your boss didn't ask for flags with a case statement? That's the simple, canonical method that almost all other tools use.

Comment: @thatotherguy this is exactly what he asked for:                                                 
 `case $# in
  4)
    # 3 additional input args
    - Do Stuff
    ;;
  3)
    # 2 additional input args
    - Do Stuff
    ;;
  2)
    # 1 additional input arg
    - Do Stuff
    ;;
  1)
    # 0 additional input args
    - Do Stuff
    ;;
esac`

Comment: The example has no checks like `[[ -z $1 ]] && [[ -z $2 ]] && [[ -n $3 ]]` (2 empty arguments and a filled one). It really looks like logic based on `$#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$#` you see the number of arguments. The next `case` works different when you use `""` as an argument, or have more than 3 arguments. I think it shows how you boss thinks about `case ... esac`.
The solution of Charles is better, your boss might also tell you to avoid duplicate lines.

```
case $# in
   3)
    # sudoed audit or fsr w/ IP: set user, user home directory, IP.
    CURR_USER="$1"
    CURR_HOME="$2"
    ADDR="$3";;
   2)
    # sudoed audit or fsr w/o IP: set user, user home directory.
    CURR_USER="$1"
    CURR_HOME="$2"
    ADDR='';;
   1)
    # root w/ IP: set audit user, audit home directory, IP.
    CURR_USER='audit'
    CURR_HOME='/home/audit'
    ADDR="$1";;
  *)
    # root w/o IP: set audit user, audit home directory.
    CURR_USER='audit'
    CURR_HOME='/home/audit'
    ADDR="";;
  esac
```

or using defaults

```
CURR_USER='audit'
CURR_HOME='/home/audit'
ADDR=""
case $# in
   3)
    # sudoed audit or fsr w/ IP: set user, user home directory, IP.
    CURR_USER="$1"
    CURR_HOME="$2"
    ADDR="$3";;
   2)
    # sudoed audit or fsr w/o IP: set user, user home directory.
    CURR_USER="$1"
    CURR_HOME="$2";;
   1)
    # root w/ IP: set audit user, audit home directory, IP.
    ADDR="$1";;
  *)
    # root w/o IP: set audit user, audit home directory.
    ;;
  esac
```

Answer (score 1):

This is, in short, a very bad idea. However, if you have a sigil that can't exist in your values (demonstrating with `:` below), it can be done:

```
case $1:$2:$3 in
  '::')  CURR_USER=audit; CURR_HOME=/home/audit; ADDR=;;
  *::)   CURR_USER=audit; CURR_HOME=/home/audit; ADDR=$1;;
  *:*:)  CURR_USER=$1;    CURR_HOME=$2;          ADDR=;;
  *:*:*) CURR_USER=$1;    CURR_HOME=$2;          ADDR=$3;;
esac
```

However, using the default-value parameter expansion lets you get *almost* the exact same logic much more clearly:

```
CURR_USER=${1:-audit}
CURR_HOME=${2:-/home/audit}
ADDR=$3
```

...or, for the *exact* same logic:

```
CURR_USER=${1:-audit}
CURR_HOME=${2:-/home/audit}
if [ -z "$2" ] && [ -z "$3" ]; then
  ADDR=$1
else
  ADDR=$3
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your intention is for there to be two ways to call your program:

```
Usage: my_program CURR_USER CURR_HOME [ADDR] (1st form)
  or:  my_program [ADDR] (2nd form)
```

You can write that as:

```
if (( $# >= 2 )) ; then
    # sudoed audit or fsr:
    CURR_USER="$1"
    CURR_HOME="$2"
    ADDR="$3" # may be empty
else
    # root:
    CURR_USER=audit
    CURR_HOME=/home/audit
    ADDR="$1" # may be empty
fi
```

Or:

```
if (( $# >= 2 )) ; then
    # sudoed audit or fsr:
    CURR_USER="$1"
    CURR_HOME="$2"
    shift 2
else
    # root:
    CURR_USER=audit
    CURR_HOME=/home/audit
fi
ADDR="$1" # may be empty
```